# How do I check when my transition has ended

Tags: jquery, css

I am using code from https://codepen.io/ahmadbassamemran/pen/rNjMXqg.

I need to work out how to determine once the animation has ceased but the code I have found just repeats endlessly.

```js
$('#my_search').on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', function(e) {
  if (e.target === e.currentTarget) {
    if ($(this).val()) {
      alert("Contains a value");
    } else {
      alert("No value");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-box">
  <button class="btn-search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
  <input id="my_search" type="text" class="input-search" placeholder="Type to Search...">
</div>
```

...but this just causes the alert("No value") to repeat infinitely.

Comment: Not doing anything when I run the code you've included here. Please include a [mre] that demonstrates the issue here on Stack Overflow, not only on some other site which might decide to delete your code in a couple of years.

Comment: change your alert to console.log and it stops repeating